# NoMethodError in Devise::RegistrationsController#create Undefined method user_url

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise

I created user table using devise and then added two more columns in it. Then also added the `before_action` in the Application Controller:

```rb
before_action :configure_permitted_parameters, if: :devise_controller?

protected

 def configure_permitted_parameters
    devise_parameter_sanitizer.permit(:sign_up, keys: [:name,:email,:password,:usertype])
    devise_parameter_sanitizer.permit(:account_update, keys: [:name,:email,:password,:current_password,:usertype])
  end
```

Now the issue is when I sign up it gives me an error. Transaction is committed but I guess the devise doesnt knows the url or something like that

The error I get is like this:

```
undefined method `user_url' for #<Devise::RegistrationsController:0x0000000000e100>

            if options.empty?
              recipient.public_send(method, *args)
            else
              recipient.public_send(method, *args, options)
            end
```

Comment: Please check your `routes.rb` file for devise routes

Comment: i found the solution, in rails 7 after the submit button in app/views/devise/registration/new.html.erb you have to add this:

       '''<%= f.submit "Sign up" ,data: {turbo: false}%>'''